# Python: Iterating through an API with multiple pages onto excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, api, iteration, spreadsheet

Maybe I am using the wrong excel writer, but I am attempting to pull data off a server and then organize it onto excel. The max amount of records I can pull is 500, the server has 5000 records, so normally I just pull 500 at a time. I started looking into editing my code to make it complete the process automatically through all 10 pages and send it all to excel.

The code below is the closest I have gotten to completing this task. It iterates through all the pages, I do a print to see as it does this, but on the return function, which then sends it to the spreadsheet, I only see the last page of 500 records. Is what I am trying to do possible with xlxswriter? Is there a better option, or is there a way to fix my program to complete this task?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code below is not the full code, just a portion dealing with the excel issue.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json
import time
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import xlsxwriter


def label_search(query):
    company = input('\nEnter ID: ')
    size = 500
    offset = -501
    position = '&offset='
    api_call_response = requests.get(base_url +
                                     query + company + size
                                     + position + str(offset),
                                     headers=api_call_headers,
                                     verify=False)
    for value in api_call_response:
        while offset <= 5000:
            api_call_response
            offset += 500
            print(base_url +query + company + size + position + str(offset))
        return(api_call_response).json()


def lookup():
    try:
        label = input("\nPlease provide label name: ")
        label_info = label_search(label)
        if len(label) == 0:
            print("\nPlease provide a proper label name: ")
        else:
            search = label_info
            display_wb_all(search)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print_pause("\nCouldn't connect to server! Check Network")
        menu()


def display_wb_all(search):
    row = 0
    col = 0
    wbname = input('Name your workbook: ')
    avwb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(wbname + '.xlsx')
    wsname = avwb.add_worksheet('WorkSheet1')
    cell_format = avwb.add_format()
    cell_format.set_bg_color('silver')
    cell_format.set_align('center')
    cell_format.set_align('vcenter')
    body_format = avwb.add_format()
    body_format.set_align('center')
    body_format.set_align('vcenter')
    body_format.set_bg_color('white')
    wsname.write('A1', 'Field name', cell_format)
    wsname.write('B1', 'Field name', cell_format)
    wsname.write('C1', 'Field name', cell_format)
    wsname.write('D1', 'Field name', cell_format)
    wsname.write('E1', 'Field name', cell_format)
    wsname.write('F1', 'Field name', cell_format)
    wsname.write('G1', 'Field name', cell_format)
    wsname.write('H1', 'Field name', cell_format)
    wsname.write('I1', 'Field name', cell_format)
    wsname.set_column('A:A', 35)
    wsname.set_column('B:B', 24)
    wsname.set_column('C:C', 10)
    wsname.set_column('D:D', 35)
    wsname.set_column('E:E', 19)
    wsname.set_column('F:F', 8)
    wsname.set_column('G:G', 19)
    wsname.set_column('H:H', 18)
    wsname.set_column('I:I', 11)
    for entry in search['items']:
        siteName = entry['id']
        s = entry['time']
        a = int(s or 0)/1000.0
        r = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a).strftime
             ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        try:
            state = entry['device'][0]['state']
        except TypeError:
            state = 'No Data Found'
        try:
            sim = entry['device'][0]['identifier']
        except TypeError:
            sim = 'No Data Found'
        try:
            platform = entry['device'][0]['mobile']
        except TypeError:
            platform = 'No Data Found'
        try:
            tech = entry['device'][0]['technology']
        except TypeError:
            tech = 'No Data Found'
        bytestotal = entry['usage']['bytesTotal']
        timestamp = entry['usage']['timestamp']
        ts = int(timestamp or 0)/1000.0
        x = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime
             ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        limit = entry['dataUsage']['limit']
        row += 1
        wsname.write(row, col, siteName, body_format)
        wsname.write(row, col + 1, r, body_format)
        wsname.write(row, col + 2, state, body_format)
        wsname.write(row, col + 3, sim, body_format)
        wsname.write(row, col + 4, platform, body_format)
        wsname.write(row, col + 5, tech, body_format)
        wsname.write(row, col + 6, bytestotal, body_format)
        wsname.write(row, col + 7, x, body_format)
        wsname.write(row, col + 8, limit, body_format)
    avwb.close()
    print(os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to open, and write to an existing Excel file after the first request, which isn't possible in xlsxwriter. So everytime you call the write function, you overwrite the existing file, hence ending up with only data from the last API call.

> https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/introduction.html
>
> Disadvantages:
>   It cannot read or modify existing Excel XLSX files.

You could use `openpyxl` to do this as it supports modification.

Comment: My idea was to pull all the data once by iterating the API call and then sending all the data at once to the excel doc, that way it only opens the workbook once then saves and closes. Reading up on openpyxl now, seems to be better option.

Comment: As far as my code should I seperate the API calls and excel print statements so when I iterate through the 10 pages of data each one is handled separately, rather than in a cluster like I have it now?

Comment: in `for value in api_call_response` is that an iteration over all the separate 500 page returns?

Comment: Yes, each pages allows 500 records, and I have the iteration going by the offset value of the url I am sending to the server. So for each call that number changes by 500 so I do not overlap data.

Comment: Your `return` is inside the loop, which would cause it to only return after one loop. This could possibly be contributing to your issue. I would say its better to use `openpyxl` to be fair.

Comment: Heres is what it looks like when it prints out in the terminal

www.whatever.com/api/labels=generic label&company=sdjkghfjksdfhgsdjhg&size=500&offset=0
www.whatever.com/api/labels=generic label&company=sdjkghfjksdfhgsdjhg&size=500&offset=500
www.whatever.com/api/labels=generic label&company=sdjkghfjksdfhgsdjhg&size=500&offset=1000

Comment: Makes sense. Let me give it one more try, then I will switch to openpyxl